# How can i totally Prevent user to access my application by by passing the anti-phishing error message option

Tags: asp.net, security

My application is deployed over a local intranet.I created a self signed certicated and deploy my application over https,using the this certificate.My main goal is to totally not allow users to access my application if the certificate is not install on their client pc.Currently when  user try accessing the site,it display the anti-phishing error message giving option to users to continue. I want to make sure atleast clients must have the certificate otherwise should not access the site. If there is option to specify specific ip address that should access the site is also appreciated.

Comment: Restricting by IP address is easy: http://omensblog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/restricting-website-access-by-ip.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My main goal is to totally not allow users to access my application if the certificate is not install on their client pc.

Server certificates like the one you have deployed *only* allow the client to identify the server; they are no use in verifying anything about the client to the server.

It sounds like what you really want is to install *client* certificates on the desktops in the intranet, and set the server to accept connections only from clients with certs. The IIS side of this is easy to do - in IIS Manager use 'SSL Settings' -> 'Client certificates' -> 'Require' on the site in question.

But you then need to make sure IIS trusts the CA you used to issue the client certificate(s). To do this you need to install the CA cert into the trusted roots on the IIS server machine... but you have to make sure to add it to the Computer cert store (which the IIS service user will see) and *not* your own user cert store which is what comes up by default when you run the Certificate Manager. [about this](https://superuser.com/questions/249484/how-can-i-start-certmgr-msc-for-computer-account)

Ideally you should be setting up a CA and issuing different certificates to each machine or user - and as this gets bigger, there can be quite an overhead in running the CA, to manage expiry/reissue and revocation properly. If you are in a Windows domain setup you may wish to look at using Active Directory Certificate Services to help run the PKI and roll out the certs.

An IP address filter is much more straightforward. Ensure you have installed the "IP and Domain Restrictions" feature for the Web Server Role ("IP Security" if you're running it on a client OS) then click the "IPv4 address and domain restrictions" feature on the site in IIS Manager. See [this](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity) for details and how to set it directly in web.config if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for sounds like Client certificates.  What you have set up now is a server certificate - clients can always decide to trust it, even if it is not on their machine.  What you want is for your server to only show content to clients that have a cert, correct?

Check out this page for some more information on how this could be implemented:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api